# Monotouch consuming ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: xamarin.ios, asp.net-web-api

I have a Monotouch project that today uses WCF Web Services to get data. Now I want to migrate it in order to start using ASP.NET Web Api Json.

Does anyone know how can I send a viewmodel data from a ASP.NET Web Api and then read it in monotouch?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read this [Xamarin article](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_Web_Services).

In general, Web API is just standard HTTP passing either XML or JSON back and forth.  There is not necessarily a client framework accessing it--you can consume it with raw `HttpWebRequests` or the equivalent in whichever programming language you are using.

Considering that, your options are:

1. Use an open-source library to do it (something like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/))
2. Create the `HttpWebRequest` calls, and format the XML or JSON for the requests and responses yourself (you can use the .Net BCL to do this or other open source projects)

I tend to do the former, just because I like fine grained control of what is going on.  #1 might be easier for you though.