# Monotouch consuming WebAPI FileContentResult

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.ios

Does anyone have any experience consuming a ASP.NET WebApi call that returns a FileContentResult for a image in a MonoTouch application?

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** Yes, it is feasible to have, and you have few options to get it work:

A full fledge article that disucess it is - [Xamarin - Introduction to Web Services](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services).

In addition, here is a SP post on this topic that seems addresses your issue - [Monotouch consuming ASP.NET Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12567232/1437962).

Comment: Thanks. I actually got it to work using a HttpWebRequest and a BinaryReader.